# Where do I define textViews within a fragment to change its content multiple time?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

so I have this fragment which includes multiple TextView that gets changed when user clicks on a **"next"** button or **"previous"** button.

within the onCreateView method i have:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time_table, container, false);


    update(inflatedView,worker.current.getTarih(),worker.current.getHicri(),worker.current.getGün(),worker.current.getImsak(),worker.current.getSabah(),worker.current.getGüneş(),worker.current.getÖğle(),worker.current.getIkindi(),worker.current.getAkşam(),worker.current.getYatsı());


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflatedView;


}
```

on the update method I have

```
public void update(View dimension,String tarih, String hicri, String gun, String imsak, String sabah, String gunes, String ogle, String ikindi, String aksam, String yatsi){

    TextView gunView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.gun);
    TextView imsakView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.imsak);
    TextView sabahView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.sabah);
    TextView gunesView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.gunes);
    TextView ogleView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.ogle);
    TextView ikindiView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.ikindi);
    TextView aksamView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.aksam);
    TextView yatsiView = (TextView) dimension.findViewById(R.id.yatsi);


    gunView.setText(gun);
    imsakView.setText(imsak);
    sabahView.setText(sabah);
    gunesView.setText(gunes);
    ogleView.setText(ogle);
    ikindiView.setText(ikindi);
    aksamView.setText(aksam);
    yatsiView.setText(yatsi);
}
```

the update method gets called on user click. It occurs to me that the textview is redefined everytime `update()` is called. **I tried defining TextView on the onCreate method but I kept on getting NPE.**

Comment: I bet some part of `worker` is null... Hard to tell without the logcat though

Comment: in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated` (you need to return a `View` instance variable in `onCreateView` as you need access to it outside of `onCreateView`)

Comment: You should really just pass `worker.current` as one parameter to the `update` method. There is no point in splitting all the fields for that one object

Comment: oh right, changed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change like this way,

**By doing this way, your textview will not be redefined everytime**

change :

```
public class ViewFragment extends Fragment {

    public TextView gunView, imsakView, sabahView, gunesView, ogleView, ikindiView, aksamView, yatsiView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
        gunView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.gun);
        imsakView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.imsak);
        sabahView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.sabah);
        gunesView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.gunes);
        ogleView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.ogle);
        ikindiView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.ikindi);
        aksamView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.aksam);
        yatsiView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.yatsi);
        update("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");  //remove view from here
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflatedView;
    }

    public void update(String tarih, String hicri, String gun, String imsak, String sabah, String gunes, String ogle, String ikindi, String aksam, String yatsi) {
        gunView.setText(gun);
        imsakView.setText(imsak);
        sabahView.setText(sabah);
        gunesView.setText(gunes);
        ogleView.setText(ogle);
        ikindiView.setText(ikindi);
        aksamView.setText(aksam);
        yatsiView.setText(yatsi);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this prevent the NullPointerException? All you did was move some lines from the update method into OnCreateView

Comment: I tried that before but then I'm getting error on the update method. I'm getting " Cannot resolve symbol ... "

Comment: please check my updated answer. i am not getting any errors.@BillyBatson

Comment: Sure, your code will compile, but the question was why there is an NPE.My guess is some id is missing or incorrect from findViewById

Comment: here, mainly question is solved now @BillyBatson does not need to define textviews everytime.

Answer (score -1):

here's my thought, hope it works, I havent tried it myself. If you would want to define TextView and not redefine it over and over again, why not do it inside of your fragment class using ButterKnife after compiling with gradle option (compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1').

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        @Bind(R.id.textView)TextView tv;
        @Bind(R.id.textView)TextView tv2, tv3 etc;
    ...
    ...
        @Override
        OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance){
          ButterKnife.Bind(getActivity());
   }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

          tv.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "ABCD %d", i));
    }
```

Comment: Please try to respect the intention of the original code. You can suggest libraries in the comments